# Trouble Building Windows Server Core Containers with Python Image

Tags: python, windows, docker, image, containers

I'm facing difficulties building Windows Server Core containers using Python images, specifically with tags like `python:3.11.5-windowsservercore`. While I can successfully build containers using other Python tags, I'm encountering an issue with these Windows Server Core-based images.

Here's my Dockerfile contents:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=python:3.11.5-windowsservercore
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
```

However, when I attempt to build the container, I encounter the following error:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.5-windowsservercore
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.5-windowsservercore:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:d80b99d74aea127674d43c3e42d572bd2c718d6355680eeafdc1368ecb821daf: not found
```

I've confirmed that the image I'm trying to use is available on Docker Hub, and you can find it at the following link: [Python 3.11.5 on Windows Server Core](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/python/3.11.5-windowsservercore/images/sha256-a5f77c43352fc785909f71e051e88fe271fe2f4607e1f2bcd0d030d3e489e217?context=explore).